# Nextcloud: "Mounting" shared link

Tags: nextcloud

A user on another Nextcloud installation has shared a link publicly: `https://nextcloud.example.com/s/nBHBu6KioeEgrmA`. How can I "mount" that in my local Nextcloud installation, so that when new files are available they will automatically be copied to my Nextcloud server and then syncronized to my clients?

So user `foo` on `nextcloud.example.com` shares a link with the information to the public: `https://nextcloud.example.com/s/nBHBu6KioeEgrmA`

I am user `bar` on `nc.example.net` and I want to get `foo`'s link "mounted" into `nc.example.net` so that I can access it just as if it had been shared through federation.

The problem is related to sharing a federated link, but in this case the link is not shared to a specific group but to the general public.

Comment: How it is shared, NFS, SMB, FTP, rsync...? And you do not need to mount it, better ask him/her to make rsync.

Comment: @RomeoNinov It is shared though a public Nextcloud link. I have elaborated on the situation.

Comment: You can try if WebDAV work for you and try to mount it and sync.